# C++ Qt creator - curl on click

Tags: c++, curl, httprequest, qt-creator

i have problem with my code. I try to send http request to volumio API with curl. Everything working but if server is down my app freezes. How can i add try and catch to my code? or what can i do?

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
    #include <curl/curl.h>

    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

    CURLcode res;
    using namespace std;
    std::string ip1 = "http://192.168.2.5";

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
        : QMainWindow(parent)
        , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        this->setWindowTitle("New Title");
    }

    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;
    }


    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_prev_clicked()
    {
        std::string url = ip1 + "/api/v1/commands/?cmd=prev";
          curl = curl_easy_init();
          if(curl) {
            /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can
               just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the
               data. */
              curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());


            /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

            /* always cleanup */
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why call out to `curl` from a Qt application? Why not use `QNetworkAccessManager` and friends?

Comment: QNetworkAccessManager - yes that's what i'm looking for! THANK YOU so much! :)